# VirtualBoxの設定フォントが小さい

Tags: windows, virtualbox

## 環境

- Host OS: Widnows 10
- Guest OS: XUbuntu 18.04
- ノートPC: 15インチ
- 外部ディスプレイ：42インチ(4K)

#### VirtualBox

VirtualBox グラフィカルユーザーインターフェース
バージョン 6.0.8 r130520 (Qt5.6.2)
Copyright © 2019 Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

## 現象

### ノートPCに表示

ノートPC上でVirtulBoxマネージャを開くと、VirtulBoxマネージャのフォントが小さすぎて見えません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ノートPCのディスプレイ設定は下図の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、VirtualBox VMの表示設定は100%ですが、フォントが小さいです。
表示設定を200%に変更したら、適切なフォントサイズになりました。

#### 外部ディスプレイに接続

外部ディスプレイでVirtulBoxマネージャを開くと、VirtulBoxマネージャのフォントは適切な大きさです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、VirtualBox VMの表示設定は100%で、フォントは適切なサイズです。

## 質問

ノートPCに表示したとき、VirtualBoxマネージャのフォントを適切なサイズに変更にするには、どうすればよいでしょうか？
また、ディスプレイを切り替えたときに、自動的にVirtualBox VMの表示設定を変えるには、どのように設定すればよいでしょうか？
「表示設定」を手動で変えなくても、適切なフォントサイズになるようにしたいです。

Comment: VirtualBoxが表示のスケーリングに対応していないのが原因に見えます

Comment: >VirtualBoxが表示のスケーリングに対応していない
どの設定を確認すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 表示のスケーリングに対応していない場合は、テキストサイズを100%にして、モニターの解像度を下げるしかないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

最後に表示したい環境にしてから、VirtualBoxマネージャーを再起動したら、治りますよ。